# mssql 2008 - using variables as column names

Tags: sql-server-2008, variables, names

I have searched a lot to use variable names as column names, however I could not find anything. I have a table which has nameMaster column and xVariable,yVariable,zVariable underneath. I know I can use:

```
case nameMaster when 'xVariable' then total else 0 end AS xVariable
case nameMaster when 'yVariable' then total else 0 end AS yVariable
case nameMaster when 'zVariable' then total else 0 end AS zVariable
```

However I like to do this in a loop, not manually.

My table is like this:

```
nameMaster | total
---------------------
xVariable  | 10.000
yVariable  | 20.000
zVariable  | 30.000
```

What I want to display is like this:

```
xVariable | yVariable | zVariable
---------------------------------
10.000      20.000       30.000
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the thing that you want to achieve is called PIVOT table and it will transform your columns in to rows based on your columns selections.

You can [refer this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) article to see how the pivot happens.

Comment: Thank you very much Jigar!! This is what I have been looking for.

Comment: also see Roman Pekar's solution for dynamic columns in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245364/ms-sql-server-pivot-table-with-subquery-in-column-clause