# Query result based on a select statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, subquery

I have this piece of code that is a Stored Procedure that is working perfectly and it is generating a crossed fieds table from a plain table dynamically:

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @years VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @years = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT
                        '],[' + [Dimension Code]
                        FROM    MTH_ITNWF710.dbo.[Dimension Set Entry]
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 2, '') + ']'

SET @query =
'SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT [Dimension Set ID],[Dimension Code],[Dimension Value Code]
    FROM MTH_ITNWF710.dbo.[Dimension Set Entry]
)t
PIVOT (max([Dimension Value Code]) FOR [Dimension Code]
IN ('+@years+')) AS pvt'

EXECUTE (@query)
```

It is my understanding that it is not possible to create a live VIEW based on a dynamic stored procedure like the above so i wanted to convert the SP above into a nested query like the one here below to be able to create a view based on the nested query instead on a SP:

```
    SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT [Dimension Set ID],[Dimension Code],[Dimension Value Code]
    FROM MTH_ITNWF710.dbo.[Dimension Set Entry]
)t
PIVOT (max([Dimension Value Code]) FOR [Dimension Code]
IN (

SELECT STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT
                        '],[' + [Dimension Code]
                        FROM    MTH_ITNWF710.dbo.[Dimension Set Entry]
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 2, '') + ']'

)) AS pvt
```

But this is not working it is always saying that there is an error near the SELECT statement. It is my suspect that the SELECT STUFF... statement is wrongly reported as nested into the first SELECT.

Any idea?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're trying to trick sql server into letting you create a view where the columns can change dynamically, don't bother.  SQL Server won't create views where the columns can change.   You are getting the error because you can't use a sub-select in the IN() part of a PIVOT.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245364/ms-sql-server-pivot-table-with-subquery-in-column-clause

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I was suspecting something like that but what seems strange to me is that before trying to do this directly on the SQL Server i made a bridge connector file with Access where i created three queries, one standard, one pivot and a third view on the other two picking up data from the same SQL Server and retrieving data with Excel everything is working through the bridge. On top of that if i substitute the SELECT STUFF nested query with its result it works. Many Thanks

Comment: I can't picture what you're describing because I don't know what a bridge connector is, and I never work with Access, but if you're saying you can get it to work in Access, all I can say is, it must be an Access thing.

Comment: A bridge connector is an access file without any real table but only linked tables to the SQL Server and some VIEWS based on the linked tables so that when you retreive data from Excel through the Access file you are retreiving data from SQL Server through the Access Views. I thought maybe in error that being able to do that dynamic query Access it was much more possible that SQL Server could do the same or more. As an SQL expert do you see how to do the same? I was thinking to trigger a CREATE TABLE based on the SP each time a record is inserted into the base table? What do you think?

Comment: You can certainly do a dynamic CREATE TABLE based on the results of the SP.   You just can't create a VIEW with dynamic columns.