# Applying PIVOT in T-SQL to get rows to column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I know this has been asked [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13245457/1584140) also, but it seems that I'm unable to apply solutions to my requirement

I need a to apply PIVOT such that this Table(generated from joins):

```
    Category    |   Tag     |   Title
    ----------------------------------
    First       |   Tag 1   |   Article 1
    Second      |   Tag 2   |   Article 1
    Third       |   Tag 4   |   Article 1
    First       |   Tag 1   |   Article 2
    Second      |   Tag 4   |   Article 2
    Third       |   Tag 5   |   Article 2
    First       |   Tag 1   |   Article 5
    Third       |   Tag 7   |   Article 5
    First       |   Tag 8   |   Article 7
```

Becomes:

```
    Title       |   First   |   Second  |   Third
    ---------------------------------------------
    Article 1   |   Tag 1   |   Tag 2   |   Tag 4
    Article 2   |   Tag 1   |   Tag 4   |   Tag 5
    Article 5   |   Tag 1   |   NULL    |   Tag 7
    Article 7   |   Tag 8   |   NULL    |   NULL
```

Here is my Query:

```
    declare
        @cols nvarchar(max),
        @stmt nvarchar(max)

    select @cols = isnull(@cols + ', ', '') + '[' + T.CategoryTypeTitle + ']' from (select  CategoryTypeTitle from CategoryTypes) as T

    Select @stmt = '
    select Distinct * from
    (
        Select  
        C.CategoryTypeTitle, 
        A.* from Articles A 
        Join
        ArticleToTags AT on AT.ArticleID = A.ArticleID
        Join
        Tags T on T.CategoryID = AT.CategoryID
        Join
        CategoryTypes C on C.CategoryTypeID = T.CategoryTypeID
    ) src
    PIVOT
    (
        Count(Title) --**I need Tag Names (i.e. "Tag 1, Tag 2") instead of getting count or max etc**
        for [CategoryTypeTitle] in ('+ @cols +')
    ) as piv
    '
    Exec sp_executesql @stmt = @stmt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've managed to bury what I think is your actual problem deep down in your code sample. The issue seems to be that you want to just get a string value, and most samples you've found are using `COUNT()` or `AVG()`.

Well, you always have to use an aggregate. So what you need is an aggregate that can work with strings. Luckily, `MIN()` and `MAX()` do, and if they're only ever given a single value as input, that will be the entire output.

So just use `MAX(Title)` rather than `Count(Title)`.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks :)