# Convert horizontal table to vertical in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have the following table format:

```
 ID | Key | Value
 --   ---   -----
 1     A     aa    
 2     B     bb
 3     A     ay
 4     C     cc
 5     B     bx
 6     C     ct
```

I need to convert this table to following format:

**Output:**

```
 A    B    C
---  ---  ---
aa   bb   cc
ay   bx   ct
```

I looked for PIVOT function in oracle 11g, but the "Key" values in input table is not a fixed set of values, they can be anything. 
I also looked for other such questions but I am not sure in my case, how the query should be written.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

**Edited:**

For the solution, I want to execute the following query but it gives me error at subquery of IN clause. I don't understand why is that.

```
Select * from (Select Key, Value, Id from tableName
pivot (max(Value) for Key IN (SELECT distinct Key from tableName)));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the pivot function as below.

```
   select * from
    (select Key,Value from yourtable) 
    pivot(max(Value) for Key in ('A', 'B', 'C'));
```

A subquery in pivot is used only in conjunction with the XML keyword

Make your query as below:

```
Select * from (Select Key, Value, Id from tableName)
pivot xml (max(Value) for Key IN (SELECT distinct Key from tableName));
```

Comment: Thanks @Tom but making the parentheses as you suggested, did not solve the problem. I dont know why I find no such example for Pivot with sub query.

Comment: I think you have to use `pivot xml` for using sub-query. You will get the output as in xml format.

Comment: Hmm, but I need the output in tabular form without xml tags, so I would rather first execute the sub query and use its result in the Pivot query. Thanks!

Comment: @OutOfMind I have seen such questions for converting xml in to tabluar forms in SO. But ithink they uses cursor or procs or something like that. Better you can open a new question for that. Even I am curious to know the answer :)

Comment: Hey @Tom, posted a question for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42851887/convert-pivot-xml-output-to-tabular-output-without-xml

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic sql as you have said that the key is not fixed 
create a string for keys this will help you. pass this string to you pivot function as the keys are in string so this will help you.

Comment: Thanks @Rohit, I edited the question, please take a look at it. Does Pivot function allow such a subquery? Or I would have to use Dynamic Sql as per your suggestion?

Comment: I think sub query wont help you please go the link for understanding how dynamic query in pivot table will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245364/ms-sql-server-pivot-table-with-subquery-in-column-clause

Comment: @RohitGupta The link you have added is foe Sql Server. The question is for `oracle`

Comment: Sir the question has also the tag for sql server and the link will help how this can be implemented in oracle as well.