# Convert Pivot xml output to tabular output without xml

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pivot, pivot-xml

I have following kind of table:

```
 ID | Key | Value
 --   ---   -----
 1     A     aa    
 2     B     bb
 3     A     ay
 4     C     cc
 5     B     bx
 6     C     ct
```

I need the output :

```
A    B    C
---  ---  ---
aa   bb   cc
ay   bx   ct
```

When I use PIVOT with subquery it does not work:

```
Select * from (Select Key, Value, Id from tableName
pivot (max(Value) for Key IN (SELECT distinct Key from tableName)));
```

If I use PIVOT xml, the subquery works:

```
Select * from (Select Key, Value, Id from tableName)
pivot xml (max(Value) for Key IN (SELECT distinct Key from tableName));
```

but when using PIVOT xml I get the output in xml form:

```
 A                      B    C
---                    ---  ---
<PivotSet><item...aa   ...   ...
```

How can this be converted to tabular output without the xml tags? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!